# Int not callable/ not subscriptable in 2d array in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I believe is the relevant part of the code to the error. cost is a value, and uniquecodes changes each time

```
dailyorders = []
uniquecode = 0
orders = [uniquecode, cost]
dailyorders.append(orders)

dailytakings = 0
print (dailyorders)
for f in range (0, len(dailyorders)):
    dailytakings = dailytakings + dailyorders[f[1]]
```

Error code displays the following if "[f[1]]" uses square brackets.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/JD/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/menu.py", line 
58, in <module>
dailytakings = dailytakings + dailyorders[f[1]]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

And the following if "[f(1)]"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/JD/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/menu.py", line 
58, in <module>
dailytakings = dailytakings + dailyorders[f(1)]
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: `f` is an integer from your `range` and `f[1]` is the syntax for indexing. It's not clear to me what you expect the code to do instead.

Comment: Please explain in prose what it is that you are trying to accomplish here and what you are trying to see. The error and the reason for it are quite clear. What is not clear are your goals based on the provided information.

Comment: do you perhaps mean `dailyorders[f][1]`?

Comment: The problem was the indexing, I had forgotten to use it as a separate square bracket, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the element 1 in dailyorders, move your index reference after using the range counter.

```
dailyorders = []
uniquecode = 0
orders = [uniquecode, cost]
dailyorders.append(orders)

dailytakings = 0
print (dailyorders)
for f in range (0, len(dailyorders)):
    dailytakings = dailytakings + dailyorders[f][1]
```